# Is there a known algorithm for finding the shortest distance between nodes with the same distance between each pair?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

In other words, I'm wondering whether there's a known algorithm for finding the least number of moves between nodes to get from one to another. For example, I might have a tree like

```
A - B - C - D
 \     /  \
  E - F -  G
```

and I want the shortest path from `A` to `G`. That would be either `A->B->C->G` or `A->E->F->F`.

To put this in more concrete terms, I have a

```
var nodes = new List<Node>
```

where

```
class Node
{
    // ... properties

    List<Node> Neighbors;
}
```

and given some `Node start, end;` in `nodes` I want to find the shortest path from `start` to `end`.

I know I could use Djikstra's algorithm with distance `1` between every node, but I figure there's a better way for this case?

Comment: No.  Djikstra's is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **BFS** traversal is the fastest way to solve this problem, cause it will solve the problem in **linear time O(m + n)**.

The **BFS** is a **level order traversal** meaning it traverses nodes level by level:( *first all nodes at a distance of 1 edge are traversed and at a distance of 2 edges are traversed and so on.*).

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra with distance 1 or BFS - both can be applied. This type of problems are renowned to be solved by these two approaches. I don't think there's any other better way.